# Mysql query (order by) very slow

Tags: mysql

When I use ORDER BY from another table, than very slowly it work. How make the query

```
SELECT u.*, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM operations o WHERE o.userId=u.userId and o.status=1) as countOperations FROM users u ORDER BY countOperations
```

Comment: You need to provide your TABLE CREATE statements for used tables and explain result for the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is not well formed. Try the query below:

```
select col1, col2, ..., coln, count(id) countOperations, SUM(o.sumRUB) sumRUB
from users u
inner join operations o 
  on o.userId=u.userId and o.status=1
group by col1, col2, ..., coln
ORDER BY countOperations
```

you may also need index on `operations(userId, status)` and possibly (you may not require) on `users(col1, col2, ..., coln)`

Comment: so, if 2 subquery?
`SELECT u.*, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM operations o WHERE o.userId=u.userId and o.status=1) as countOperations, (SELECT SUM(o.sumRUB) FROM operations o WHERE o.userId=u.userId AND o.status=1) as sumOp FROM users u ORDER BY countOperations`